# Can one use the expression "[feel/experience/...] dissonance [... with]" to express antipathy?

Tags: grammaticality

I'm unsure how to correctly use the word dissonance in relation to myself - do I feel dissonance, do I experience it, or something else?

The sentence I have is:

> I have been open regarding the *dissonance* I experience with the values, culture and decisions of the department.

Is it ok to use the word dissonance in this way?

Comment: Look up Festinger's cognitive dissonance theory on Wikipedia and in a dictionary.  You may not be saying what you intend here.

Comment: Dissonance normally refers to internal conflict, not conflict between you and someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is fine. True, the commenters are correct in saying that *dissonance* is nowadays most often used in the phrase *cognitive dissonance,* and even when it isn't, it tends to refer to internal conflict. However, the word does get used the way you want to use it, too.

The second definition of *dissonance* in the OED is

> Want of concord or harmony (between things); disagreement, incongruity;

Examples given are

> 1826   W. Kirby & W. Spence Introd. Entomol. (1828) IV. xlvii. 381
> *This puzzling variation and **dissonance** between the different tribes.*
>  1871   J. Tyndall Fragm. Sci. (1879) I. iii. 83   *The
> molecules..are in **dissonance** with the luminous rays.*

Here are some more contemporary examples:

*Part of the **dissonance** we experienced with the linemen, and with other areas too, is what I like to call "constructive tension."* [(source)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Reengineering_the_Corporation/mjvGTXgFl6cC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22dissonance+we+experienced+with%22&pg=PA180&printsec=frontcover)
*The very **dissonance** they experienced with parents may partly reflect the differences between adolescence and adulthood.* [(source)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Generations_of_Exclusion/VAiGAwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22dissonance+they+experienced+with%22&pg=PA34&printsec=frontcover)
*In the case of my **dissonance** with the world of white evangelicalism, …* [(source)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Uncommon_Ground/s_qwDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22my+dissonance+with%22&pg=PA123&printsec=frontcover)
*I had assumed my **dissonance** with the show came from the casual way I had approached its viewing.* [(source)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/NITPICKER_S_GUIDE_FOR_DEEP_SPACE_NEXT/zR6cAAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22my+dissonance+with%22&pg=PT172&printsec=frontcover)

*Feel* works, too:

*It is early and the quiet of the vanishing night lingers except for the swooshing sound of my footsteps, exaggerating the **dissonance** I **feel** with the vast landscape.* [(source)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Being_Palestinian/cHUxEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22dissonance+I+feel+with%22&pg=PT226&printsec=frontcover)